# Doubt regarding a question on continuity.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification

**Suppose that $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$. Show that every continuous
real function with domain $S$ has closed range if, and only if, $S$ is closed
in $\mathbb R$**.

The book of Searcoid asks us to prove it.It is true that if $S$ is not closed then there would exist a function $f(x)=x$ that is continuous on $S$ but $f(S)$ is not closed.But if $S$ is closed,what is the guarantee that $f(S)$ should be closed.Take the example $\arctan :[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$,where $f(S)=[0,\pi/2)$ not closed.

Comment: You're right, the "if" half of the problem is false. Your counterexample is correct, but you don't need anything as complicated as arctan. The function $x\mapsto1/x$ maps the closed set $[1,\infty)$ onto the non-closed set $(0,1]$. The statement in the problem would become correct if $S$ were required to be bounded.  It would also become correct if $\mathbb R$ were replaced with the extended real line $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$.